# Swipebox: Stop control bars from hiding

Tags: jquery

I am using the [Swipebox](http://brutaldesign.github.io/swipebox/) jQuery lightbox.

Under normal circumstances the title of the image and the cursor arrows slide off the top and bottom of the page when swiping through the gallery.

Basically, I want the image title and the control arrows to stay in place (not slide off the page). Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is in the intial settings, just set it like this:

`hideBarsDelay : 3000, // 0 to always show caption and action bar`

see https://github.com/brutaldesign/swipebox#options

Comment: Now the bars do not slide away, but they still cover top and bottom parts of the image. Any idea how fit the whole image between top and bottom bar?

Answer (score 4):

Fixed this by putting

```
#swipebox-caption{top:0!important;}
#swipebox-action{bottom:0!important;}
```

in my css.

Comment: I also had to add: transform: initial !important

Answer (score 0):

This works for me

```
#swipebox-top-bar,#swipebox-bottom-bar{transform: none !important;}
#swipebox-top-bar{top: 0;}
#swipebox-bottom-bar{bottom:0;}
```